# No visible @interface for 'NSXMLParser' declares the selector parseXML

Tags: xcode, interface, nsxmlparser

I have this files:

XMLParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{

    NSXMLParser *parser;

}

-(id)initWitData:(NSData *)data;
-(void)parseXML;


@end
```

XMLParser.m (part of it)

```
 #import "XMLParser.h"
 @implementation XMLParser

- (id)initWitData:(NSData *)data
 {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
}
return self;
}


 - (void)parseXML{

[parser parse];

 };
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{

   NSXMLParser *xmlToString;
}


@end
```

and the ViewController.m

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"world" ofType:@"xml"];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath];
xmlToString = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
//[xmlToString setDelegate:self];
[xmlToString setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
[xmlToString parseXML]; // I am getting the error here.
```

}

Can anybody help me? I have done almost the same in other project and its working!!! The only difference is the initWithData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an `NSXMLParser` and then trying to call a method from `XMLParser` on it. Are you sure you didn't mean to declare `xmlToString` as an `XMLParser*` and then say

```
xmlToString = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Of course, your call to `-setShouldResolveExternalEntities:` will then fail, so you may need to expose your underlying `NSXMLParser` object.

Comment: I have created the parseXML function. I tried what you said but then I get almost the same error for     xmlToString = [[XMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];

Comment: Actually the problem is that I created XMLParser which is already exists. Even when I renamed the XMLParser to XMLParserC I got error here:     xmlToString = [[XMLParserC alloc]initWithData:data]; for incompatible pointer types and the same error for [xmlToString parseXML]